# How can I loop through my "getElementById" VBA for multiple websites?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, extract

I'm part of a non-profit that sends letters to encourage hundreds of people in prison. They are often transferred unexpectedly, with no time to give notice of address change. However, each person's location while incarcerated **is** kept up-to-date and publicly accessible on the state government's website.

I am trying to write VBA that goes through my "contact" list and visits each state government's prisoner location website (based on each prisoner's ID), then extracts each person's location from the website, places that in a column ($C) for that purpose which corresponds to the row for that specific person's name & ID. That way I could run a check automatically to confirm each one is still at the same location before I do an Excel mailmerge to print envelope labels with their addresses.

- The website is the same for each one, changed only by their prisoner ID at the end (e.g., http://mdocweb.state.mi.us/OTIS2/otis2profile.aspx?mdocNumber=226475)
- All I need is to confirm the correctional facility — so I need to extract just one item from each prisoner's respective page. I've been able to successfully extract it for one person, but am having trouble using a proper loop sequence to get the next one, and output it into the same row.

Here's what I'm using to get the correct value (I've just been testing with a MsgBox CFTitle)

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "http://mdocweb.state.mi.us/OTIS2/otis2profile.aspx?mdocNumber=" & Range("PrisonerID").Value
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document
Dim CFTitle As String
CFTitle = Trim(Doc.getElementById("valLocation").innerText)
```

And here is a screenshot of an example list of names (with actual Prisoner IDs), using the same columns as my list:
[Example of Excel Contact Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Nxy.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick way.

I read the prisoner ids into  an array from a sheet (column K). If you read in from a sheet you get a 2D array and then loop the first dimension to get the ids.

I loop that array issuing a browserless XHR request for each id. This is a quick way to retrieve your information via `GET` request.

I use `.getElementById("valLocation")` to get the correctional facility information.

I store these results in an array called `facilities`.

At the end I write the ids and locations out to the sheet, column C, with:

```
.Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(facilities) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(facilities)
```

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, ids(), facilities(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet, counter As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<==change as appropriate
    ids = ws.Range("K2:K" & GetLastRow(ws)).Value
    ReDim facilities(UBound(ids, 1) - 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo errhand
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(ids, 1) To UBound(ids, 1)
            counter = counter + 1
            .Open "GET", "http://mdocweb.state.mi.us/OTIS2/otis2profile.aspx?mdocNumber=" & ids(i, 1), False
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

            With CreateObject("htmlFile")
                .Write sResponse
                facilities(i - 1) = .getElementById("valLocation").innerText
            End With
NextId:
        Next i
    End With
    With ws
        .Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(facilities) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(facilities)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

errhand:
    Debug.Print counter
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 91
        Err.Clear
        facilities(i - 1) = "Not found"
        GoTo NextId
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

---

**Result in the sheet:**

[image: Result in sheet]

Comment: This worked splendidly on my test data, but when I ran it on my entire list of over 300 lines, I discovered it could only run on a varying number of entries (between 10-150), or it would give the "Run-time error '91' -- Object variable or With block variable not set." Alternately, sometimes it would give the same "Object variable or With block variable not set" without naming 91 specifically. When I debug, it goes to the line of   "  facilities(i - 1) = .getElementById("valLocation").innerText "   I'm not seeing anything that should limit it being used on -- any thoughts? Thanks much!

Comment: Potentially, if you provide me with a full list I can debug from this end. Also, some sites may not like large numbers of requests within a short span of time.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, @QHarr, I do wonder if it is something external since there is such variation between the number of IDs it can process. Sometimes it won't process 5, while once it processed 150 at once. [Here's a long list to test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut2wl4a713vau7v/test-long-list_PrisonerIDs.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Some who are discharged return "" for id valLocation -- but it has still worked for those, just nicely outputting "" into column C. I did find one erroneous ID (a typo), which stopped the code and gave a red warning box (can't remember what it said unfortunately, and now I can only get run-time error 91)

Comment: Do you have the full list? It ran for me with the exception of one not found which I put some error handling in for. Updated code above. I can improve error handling with longer list. Is it possible you have any network/bandwidth problems btw? Your current results: https://file.io/eQFlqV

Comment: your responsiveness and "going the extra mile" has been amazing, and I've learned a lot! The "supplemental info" you pulled & pivoted is very interesting, and gave me lots of ideas -- and I added a name pulling line which is very useful!
Here's the full list: [https://file.io/xoidbI](https://file.io/xoidbI) -- when I try to run it on the full 500+ names, it either gives me a run-time error 91, for the [facilities(i - 1) = .getElementById("valLocation").innerText] line, or a run-time error that timed out the operation, debugging showed the [.send] line after the [.Open "GET"] line.

Comment: It was interesting and for a good cause. I will have a look at the full list today and get back to you. Any additional items whilst I am at it? I will add in Names.

Comment: It does appear that I may be dealing with a network/bandwidth problem (or something else?), since the code worked just fine for the 309 IDs once, but trying it again just gave me error 91.

Comment: Ultimately my goal was to write a separate VBA that would also pull the addresses of the facilities (from a table in another sheet, where I would input the correct address once) and add the address next to names for mailmerges. 

Could another problem be that I don't have the correct "References" selected in my VBA/Excel?  I've not previously used the .GET / XHR queries.

It confuses me that the code will run fine once, but running it again a little later it will give me an error, usually 91. This wouldn't be affected by how I activate the macro -- i.e. as module or as code under a sheet?

Comment: I think in part it is about connection. I am currently testing to see what I can do about error handling.

Comment: Superb!! Yes, I am able to add references: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/2hnZsCi)

Comment: So not my finest work I'll admit. Here are the results.  I had to switch to internet explorer as I couldn't xhr the individual facility sites using the links to them that I grabbed in the first query which issued the XHRs. I have, for now, grabbed the 2 tables on each page that give the short and long facility descriptions. Take a look and feedback. We can then refine. Or I can guide you and you can have a go if you prefer. I don't want to dominate your project. https://file.io/SXm85P

Comment: I have taken all the text as there is no guarantee that each table holding the address on each page has the same sheet styling/layout. It is hard to therefore target the address specifically. An example query where I drill into a table cell (i.e. one cell in the table) still retrieves a little bit more than just address and there is no guarantee styling will hold across pages. Have a look: http://try.jsoup.org/~CtYgFPXApbdYhJIkLlIxsM3nc3k . That is not to say we can't parse the returned string to pull out the address in a different way.

Comment: Second link you need to scroll down to where it says "Select" to see the result of the query I wrote against the page styling for one of the links. The top bit is the page HTML imported.

Comment: I forgot to add .Quit into module 4. You will always want to quit the IE application at the end.

Comment: Yes -- the inconsistent address styling was the reason I was not even trying for it yet. Since we write people mostly in Michigan prisons at this point, and that means up to 31 locations, I think it is easiest (prison addresses rarely change), to pull from an internal Excel table, matching the Correctional Facility title.  

Here is the table I'm thinking to draw addresses from, internally: [https://file.io/ojqwCj](https://file.io/ojqwCj) so "If FullList column $C matches Sheets("CFaddress") column $A, then paste $B:$E accordingly. I realize a VLookup function could work with this as well...

Comment: Well the latest workbook does have all the addresses in.

Comment: But all my experience in writing such tasks functions led to some pretty bloated calculations and functional but abysmally-slow worksheets. I much prefer the idea of running a macro once!

Comment: Have you checked that doing this is allowed by the way? I didn’t check and probably should have. If it isn’t allowed I won’t be able to assist any further I’m afraid.

Comment: Yes, thanks for checking -- since we work closely with the officials I did check to make sure there was no TOS issue [Website Terms of Use](https://www.michigan.gov/corrections/0,4551,7-119-1494-281460--,00.html); it is public info, "available for personal and non-commercial use." It does not reference any restrictions to accessing content or pulling information for legal use.

Comment: Also, the "I agree" you click on before running a query is here: [Search for Offender](http://mdocweb.state.mi.us/OTIS2/otis2.html) -- it mostly is about how the details cannot be guaranteed to be accurate, etc, etc. "Although every effort is made to maintain accurate records on this database, no action should be taken as a result of information found herein without confirmation with the MDOC," "The Department of Corrections and the State of Michigan offer this information without any express or implied warranty as to its accuracy."

Comment: It's actually required by Michigan law that they provide this information publically, "The Michigan Legislature requires the MDOC to keep offender information on OTIS for three years after discharge..."

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will have a look at your table. Did you review the latest workbook?

Comment: For the address is it sufficient to retrieve the ZIP code or do you need the entire address ?

Comment: Came across this as well which I may have a look at later: https://github.com/bbritten/mdoc-parser/blob/master/scraper.R

Comment: Haven’t read through but will have a look tomorrow. The last workbook. Too much text brought back?

Comment: For the zip vs. full address, honestly, it is icing on the cake, because I can add the appropriate address manually / copy paste by sorting through the table filters, by each facility-- as long as I have the correct CF listed for each person I'm writing. But to answer your question, there are often several facilities in one zipcode, as they tend to build multiple facilities adjoining.

Comment: Yes, I'm amazed at what you were able to pull from that relative mess, but still think it will be simpler to just copy from internal sheet where I've neatly listed the CF address, than parsing all the text (which will likely vary by site / depend on who updates or doesn't update their websites)

Comment: So here is a quick mess around. It uses your address list and looks for an exact match. If exact match it outputs direct, if not exact match if defaults to looping each match on zipcode, against previously retrieved information for table 1 on each page, and asks you to verify whether the address shown is a match. At the end you have the listed matches with hyperlinks to verify a second time against retrieved text. https://file.io/YNUkwQ

Comment: You could perhaps replace this visual step with fuzzy match logic but you would still need a visual verification step.

Comment: Thanks so much, I look forward to giving it a look tonight.

Comment: Let me know. We can look at different routes but I think you will hit the same problems if you want to use only those webpages to retrieve/validate addresses. Fuzzy might be useful if this was done a lot but you would need to have done enough times to build up a reasonably accurate matching.