# How to select value from drop down on web url?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, html-select

I am trying to select data from the dropdown in the web URL, my all code is working fine but I am unable to select the value from the dropdown.

```
Sub pulldata2()
        Dim tod As String, UnderLay As String
        Dim IE As Object
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
```

'Html table

```
    Dim Tbl As HTMLTable, Cel As HTMLTableCell, Rw As HTMLTableRow, Col As HTMLTableCol
    Dim TrgRw As Long, TrgCol As Long
```

'Create new sheet

```
    tod = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("C2").Value   
    have = False
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sht.Name = tod Then
        have = True
        Exit For
        End If
    Next sht

    If have = False Then
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = tod
    Else
    If MsgBox("Sheet " & tod & " already exists Overwrite Data?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
```

'Start Internetexplorer

```
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

Dim ColOff As Long
```

'Put data to sheet and loop to next URL

```
For Nurl = 2 To 191
ColOff = (Nurl - 2) * 23
TrgRw = 1
    UnderLay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A" & Nurl).Value
    doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = UnderLay
    doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"
```

'now i want to select data from dropdown id=date, value= 27JUN2019

```
doc.querySelector("Select[name=date] option[value=27JUN2019]").Selected = True


        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Value = UnderLay
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Font.Size = 20
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Font.Bold = True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Select
        TrgRw = TrgRw + 1


        For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
            TrgCol = 1
            For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
                TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan   ' if Column span is > 1 multiple
            Next Cel
            TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
        Next Rw

    TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
    Next Nurl
```

'exit the internetexplorer

```
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
    End Sub
```

why my code not working, I am new in VBA please help to find an error in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply alter the url rather than use dropdown

```
https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=27JUN2019
```

You can also use xhr to get the content rather than a slow browser. I use the clipboard to write out the table.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As Object, hTable As Object, ws As Worksheet, clipboard As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=27JUN2019", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Set hTable = html.getElementById("octable")
        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Alternative:

1) You could loop the tr and td within hTable above to write out the table

2) You could also use [powerquery from web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55672884/6241235) (via data tab Excel 2016+ , or using free powerquery add-in for 2013. You paste the url into the top of the pop up browser and press Go then select the table to import.

---

Changing stocks:

Stocks are part of the url query string e.g. symbol=NIFTY , so you can concatenate the new symbol into the url during a loop

```
"https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=" & yourSymbolGoesHere & "&date=27JUN2019"
```

---

If you really want to use IE be sure to encase the value of the attribute within '' e.g. `'27JUN2019'`

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub ClickButton()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Const URL As String = "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[value='27JUN2019']").Selected = True
            Stop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sir i put 200 stock name on sheet and i am looping them all so changeing url will not help. and sir  i am very new to vba so not able to use XHR request.

Comment: The stock name is part of the url - you just concatenate it in e.g. symbol=NIFTY

Comment: sir, I also try but power query is very slow and always give an error if we try to get data from many URLs like 200. I also using power query where I need to get data from 2 or 3 URLs.

Comment: I have added the Internet Explorer version in case you want to keep using that.

Comment: That should sort date selection but please let me know.

Comment: Thank you Sir changing url is working fine. Thank you so much to guiding me.

Comment: Sir, it's very helpful if you guide me about XHR to pull data. Because my process takes a long time. Please guide me how can I reduce the time.

Comment: XHR will reduce the time. This shows you how to loop reading values from a sheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118506/6241235